# Is Ajax loading too slow?

Tags: ajax

I am working on a puzzle game and everytime I load my webpage it takes a while for everything to load. I tried putting a pause until the ajax is loaded but that doesn't seem to fix it. I just want it to load more smoothly. Here is my jsfiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/X2EdH/

It's not working properly on there but it demonstrates my problem anyways.

Can anyone fix my code for me?

Here is my webpage with the puzzle:

http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~jamesber/GameOne.html#

```
var plant = "";

$.when($.ajax({"url":"http://beta.botanicalapp.com/api/v1/plants/?photo=true"}))
.done(function(fullData){
    (function(){
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*fullData.length)
        while (rand == 3) {
            rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*fullData.length)
        }
        plant = fullData[rand].plant.image_default.url;
    })()
    startGame();
});
```

Comment: How fast are you expecting it to be? Seems to take about 500-1000 ms for me - http://jsfiddle.net/89zR5/ - Are you sure its the ajax call that is slow?

Comment: I just figured there is a way for the page to load instantly with the puzzle. As of now you can see how unsmooth it is here: http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~jamesber/GameOne.html#

Comment: Oh read your comment wrong. I'm not sure why its slow. I just figured that was it